# R convert a factor in a dataframe into a vector of 0 and 1?

Tags: r, vector

I have an R data frame and I want to convert the factors in to 0's and 1's. I will use the `iris` dataset to illustrate: For example, an iris of species setosa should be expressed as 1 0 0. How would I go about doing this?

I first converted the factor to an integer:

`as.integer(iris$Species)`

What should I do next to make it into a vector?

Comment: It already is. `is.vector(as.integer(iris$Species))`.

Comment: @jenesaisquoi this worked, thank you!

Comment: It seems like you are looking for `model.matrix()`. In this case: `model.matrix(~ -1 + iris$Species)` ?